# Select next and previous id of table with same category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

| id | topic | subjectId | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Topic1 | 5 | con... |
| 2 | topic2 | 6 | con... |
| 3 | topic3 | 6 | con.... |
| 4 | Topic4 | 5 | con... |
| 5 | topic5 | 6 | con... |
| 6 | topic6 | 5 | con.... |

---

currently I selected id 4 which have subjectId 5, How to select previous id with subjectId 5, and next id with subjectId

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a Minimal, [Complete and Verifiable Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but from what I think your trying to do is get `id 1` to return based on pass `id 4` to a query.

This query does that, if you make it an stored procedure and pass an id, it will return the data you need to do whatever that is:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM #test_table
WHERE (id = @CurrentId
OR subjectid = (SELECT subjectid FROM #test_table WHERE id = @CurrentId))
AND id < @CurrentId
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: OP tagged the question with MySQL, not SQL Server. You need to remove `TOP(1)` in the SELECT clause and add a `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the next and previous ids at the same time as fetching the current topic:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT id FROM topics WHERE subjectId = t.subjectId AND id < t.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev,
    (SELECT id FROM topics WHERE subjectId = t.subjectId AND id > t.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) AS next
FROM topics t
WHERE t.id = 4;
```

Which will return:

| id | topic | subjectId | content | prev | next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Topic4 | 5 | con... | 1 | 6 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yd1X7mZx)